# Deselect all other selections if one cell selected from other section in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to deselect all other selected cells in UICollectionView in section 0 if any cell selected from section 1.
Below is what i tried so far:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SignupStep3CollectionViewCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 234.0/255.0, blue: 219.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2
    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
    }
}
```

this is not working please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

**Swift 3**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    //multiple selection in section 0 otherwise single selection in other section
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return true
    }
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    if (indexPaths?.count) ?? 0 > 0 {

        /// If you need simple way
        for index in indexPaths! {
        if index.section == indexPath.section {
            self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: index, animated: true) // if want deselect previous selection
            //return false  //if you do not want further selection
            }
        }

        /// If you need some optimization and don't want to run loop each time
        /*
        let arrIndexPaths = NSArray(array: indexPaths!)
        let sectionPrediate = NSPredicate(format: "section == %d", indexPath.section)
        let arrSelections = arrIndexPaths.filtered(using: sectionPrediate) as? [IndexPath]
        if arrSelections?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: arrSelections![0], animated: true) // if want deselect previous selection
            //return false  //if you do not want further selection
        }*/
    }

    return true
}
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    //multiple selection in section 0 otherwise single selection in other section
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return true
    }
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    if (indexPaths?.count) ?? 0 > 0 {

        /// If you need simple way
        for index in indexPaths! {
            if index.section == indexPath.section {
                self.colletionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(index, animated: true) // if want deselect previous selection
                //return false  //if you do not want further selection
            }
        }

        /// If you need some optimization and don't want to run loop each time
        /*let arrIndexPaths = NSArray(array: indexPaths!)
        let sectionPrediate = NSPredicate(format: "section == %d", indexPath.section)
        let arrSelections = arrIndexPaths.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(sectionPrediate) as? [NSIndexPath]
        if arrSelections?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            self.colletionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(arrSelections![0], animated: true) // if want deselect previous selection
            //return false  //if you do not want further selection
        }*/
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: "NSIndexpath does not confrm to protocol sequencetype" error coming

Comment: are you using Swift3? Cause this is working fine with Xcode 8.1

Comment: ok, then try to convert my code in swift 2. I think it will help you...

Comment: can you please write in swift 2 have no idea about swift 3?

Comment: This logic i have implemented already now, and also managed to clear all selections when section 1 item selected. Now facing issue is wrong selection on scroll. seems issue of deque reusability. please guide in that?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement following delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let section = indexPath.section
    let selectedRows = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    for i in 0...(selectedRows!.count - 1) {
        let path = selectedRows![i] as IndexPath
        if(path.section != section) {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: path, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

On selecting any particular item, you can get all the selected items. And then deselect all the items which are from different section.

Comment: "NSIndexpath does not confrm to protocol sequencetype" error coming

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: can you please write in swift 2 have no idea about swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Based off Mrugesh's answer, but also taking into consideration the single selection in section 1 requirement:

**Swift 2:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    if indexPaths?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
        if indexPaths![0].section != indexPath.section || indexPath.section == 1 {
            for index in indexPaths! {
                collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    if (indexPaths?.count) ?? 0 > 0 {
        if indexPaths![0].section != indexPath.section || indexPath.section == 1 {
            for index in indexPaths! {
                collectionView.deselectItem(at: index, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Depending whether your view controller is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` or just implements its delegate and datasource protocols, you may need to `override` this function.

Comment: It only allows me to make section 0 multi selection enable and section 1 single selection. but not clearing selections of section 0 if any cell from section 1 selected.

Comment: That's weird. It works for me in a simple app with a collection view, using `cell.selected` to determine what background color the cell should have. `indexPathsForSelectedItems` also prints the correct selections. I can't select section 0 and section 1 at the same time. How are you determining what is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Used below code to fix the issue:- clear section 0 selections on tap cell of section 1.
// didSelect Method

```
 let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 1)
        self.collectionViewBrands.reloadSections(indexSet)
```